# Where is wrong in this reasoning about relativity?

Tags: special-relativity

Consider two people A and B in 1-dimensional space. If in A's frame, he observes that B is $1$ light-year apart and moving at a constant speed of $c/2$ to the right, A would think if he sends a light signal, it would take $2$ light years in his frame for the signal to get to B. Because in A's frame, the relative speed of the light signal to B is $c/2$, and it takes $\frac{c}{c/2} = 2$ years to get to B.

But, if A thinks B is stationary and himself is moving to the left at constant velocity $c/2$, then if he sends a light signal to B it will cost 1 year in A's frame for B to receive it. ($t = \frac{c}{c} = 1$)

Where is wrong in this reasoning?

Comment: Your statement of the problem isn't enough precise. Try explaining step by step the calculation by which you arrive at your result, preferably illustrated with a spacetime diagram. Maybe in so doing you'll find the catch in your reasoning (hint: A's clock).

Answer (score 2):

> If in A's frame, he observes that B is $1$ light-year apart and moving
>   at a constant speed of $c/2$ to the right, A would think if he sends a
>   light signal, it would take $\frac{3}{2}$ light years in his frame for
>   the signal to get to B.

No, he wouldn't think that. It would take light $2$ years (not light-years unless you are setting $c=1$) and not $1.5$ years. Let's do this explicitly just to be sure. The trajectory of the light would be $x(t)=ct$ and the trajectory of B would be $x(t)=c \cdot 1 \text{year}+\frac{c}{2}t$ where $t$ is in years. So, they would meet when $ct=c \cdot 1 \text{year}+ct/2$ which gives us $t=2$ years.

> But, if A thinks B is stationary and himself is moving to the left at
>   constant velocity $c/2$, then if he sends a light signal to B it will
>   cost 1 year in A's frame for B to receive it.

This is "not even wrong" to use the famous phrase. Because it doesn't convey any meaning. Here, you are doing something very confusing which sounds alright in English but isn't alright in physics. You are saying that while imagining that $A$ is moving to the left and $B$ is at rest, $A$ is calculating something in $A$'s frame. This is not possible to do. If you are imagining $A$ to be moving and $B$ to be at rest then, by definition, you are working in $B$'s frame (don't get me wrong, $A$ is totally allowed to use $B$'s frame but he just can't use both the frames together).

However, what you can ask is having used $B$'s frame consistently, what would $A$ predict about observations in his own frame using the principles of relativity? This is a legitimate thing to do and it should match with what someone using $A$'s frame would observe.

Notice that while using $B$'s frame, you'd have to make sure you are taking the relativity of simultaneity seriously because the problem is set up using a language which uses the concept of simultaneity in $A$'s frame (namely, *when* $B$ is such and such distance apart, $A$ does such and such. This fact that these two things are happening at the same time would only be true in $A$'s frame, not in $B$'s). On top of that, you'd obviously need to take care of length contractions and time dilations too. But this should be straightforward once you realize that you cannot both imagine yourself to be moving and use your own frame of reference. You can imagine yourself to be moving but then you have to use someone else's frame of reference (and then go on to predict what it would all have been looked like in your frame of reference).